# Material UI - DataGrid menu colors

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I'm using the `DataGrid` component for my application in ReactJS and I am using the "native" kebab menu of it.

In my work, we have our color palette and I need to change the colors of text and switch components inside this kebab menu, but I couldn't find where I can do this. Any help?

Talking about these blue colors:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: 'color you want'
    }
  }
})


<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Component />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Comment: how did you import the `MuiThemeProvider ` from which class